# Why are we Multiplying here instead of Adding?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Three small towns designated by $A$, $B$ and $C$ are interconnected by by  a system of two-way roads as described below

[hopefully the following answer is enough info without picture]

> part a)In how many ways can Linda travel from town $A$ to town $C$?

I calculated $14$ and the answer key agrees with me.

> part b) How many different round trips can Linda travel from town $A$ to town $C$ and back to town $A$?

I said $14+14$ because you have $14$ ways to go there, and from there you have $14$ ways to go back. The answer key has $14\times14$, why?

I've been given the following tips to help determine if adding or multiplying is necessary. Does anyone have any tips to add or disagree with any of the ones on the list?

- unions, the word "either" and the word "or" suggest to use the sum rule
- instersections, the word "and" or if steps are implied suggest to use the product rule

Comment: Because for _each_ possible way from $A$ to $C$, there are $14$ possible choices for the way back. You can combine each possible choice for the one direction with each possibility for the other.

Comment: Daniel is right on the money.  I would only add that when you encounter a sequence of _independent_ events, that's when you multiply the possible outcomes of each event.  An example where the events would _not_ be independent is, say, if Alice were not permitted to use the same path on her return trip.

Comment: @Doc exactly, going there and coming back are not two independent events. You can't return from a place you never went to.

Comment: Yes, agree, but mathematically independent, in the sense that the choices of the second event do not depend on the choice of the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $14$ ways to go there, and for each of those $14$ ways there are $14$ more ways to go back.

So, if you took route $1$ there, the number of routes back is $14$. If you took route $2$ there, the number of routes back is $14$ ($28$ total). Do this $14$ times because there are $14$ routes there, and the result is $14 \times 14$.

Comment: Careful with your wording, there are 14 routes to take from A to C, not roads.

Comment: @NitinPassa I edited it.